# Using a count in a case statement

Tags: sql, count, case

I need some help with this, I am creating a view using the below SQL:

```
SELECT 

         TNTTITLE.Description_VC AS TITLE
        ,TNTCONTACT.Forename_VC AS FORENAME
        ,TNTCONTACT.Surname_VC AS SURNAME
        ,TNTCONTACTEMAIL.Reference_VC AS EMAIL  
        ,TNTHOMENUMBER_GRP.Reference_VC AS GROUP_HOME_NUMBER
       ,RENTACC.ID AS RENT_ACCOUNT_ID
       ,CONVERT(DATE,RENTACC.AccountStartDate) AS RENT_ACCOUNT_START_DT
       ,CASE
            WHEN LETOFFERS.Current_Status_ID = 42 THEN 'Complete'
        ELSE 'OTHER'
        END 
            AS STATUS
        ,ASSETTYPES.Description_VC AS ASSET_NAME
        ,CASE WHEN (SELECT MainAsset FROM RENTACC HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END


FROM RENT_ACCOUNTS AS RENTACC

        INNER JOIN LETTING_OFFERS_T AS LETOFFERS
            ON RENTACC.ID = LETOFFERS.Rent_Account_Reference_VC
                AND RENTACC.AccountEndDate IS NULL
                AND RENTACC.AccountType = 'T'

        LEFT JOIN Letting_SYS_Master_T AS LETCODES
            ON LETOFFERS.Current_Status_ID = LETCODES.CODE_ID
                AND LETCODES.Type_ID = '14'

        LEFT JOIN Asset_Assets_T AS ASSETS
            ON RENTACC.MainAsset = ASSETS.Asset_ID

        LEFT JOIN Asset_Types_T AS ASSETTYPES
            ON ASSETS.Asset_TYPE_ID = ASSETTYPES.Asset_Type_ID


        /**** MAIN CONTACT INFORMATION ****/

        LEFT JOIN Shared_Addresses_T AS TNTADDRESS
            ON ASSETS.Address_ID = TNTADDRESS.Address_ID

        LEFT JOIN Contact_Group_Contacts_T AS TNTGROUP
            ON RENTACC.ContactDatabaseReference = TNTGROUP.GROUP_ID
                AND TNTGROUP.Main_Group_Contact_BT = 1
                AND TNTGROUP.Removed_BT = 0

        LEFT JOIN CONTACT_CONTACTS_T AS TNTCONTACT
            ON TNTGROUP.Contact_ID = TNTCONTACT.Contact_ID
                AND TNTCONTACT.Current_Status_ID = 65
                AND TNTCONTACT.Deceased_Date_DT IS NULL 

        LEFT JOIN Shared_Codes_T AS TNTTITLE
            ON TNTCONTACT.Title_Code_ID = TNTTITLE.Code_ID
                AND TNTTITLE.Code_ID IN (103,104,105,106)

        /**** CONTACT EMAIL INFORMATION ****/

        LEFT JOIN Contact_Contact_Details_T AS TNTCONTACTEMAIL
            ON TNTCONTACT.Contact_ID = TNTCONTACTEMAIL.Contact_ID
                AND TNTCONTACTEMAIL.SYS_Number_Code_ID = 75
                AND TNTCONTACTEMAIL.Expiry_Date_DT IS NULL


        /**** GROUP HOME NUMBER INFORMATION  ****/

        LEFT JOIN Contact_Group_Details_T AS TNTHOMENUMBER_GRP
            ON RENTACC.ContactDatabaseReference = TNTHOMENUMBER_GRP.Group_ID
                AND TNTHOMENUMBER_GRP.Expiry_Date_DT IS NULL
                AND TNTHOMENUMBER_GRP.SYS_Number_Code_ID = 71
```

I am trying to do a count in a case statement to show any MainAsset codes in the rentacc table that appear more than once show '1' and any mainasset codes that show just once to show '0'. But this is not working. But I also want to do this in the full rentacc table (aliased for rent_accounts table) as the RENTACC is only an alias for the view.

For example:

RENT_ACCOUNTS table

```
Main Asset- 
1234 
1234 
1000 
1234
```

What I want to show in the view (RENT VIEW) is the below:

```
main asset, case
1234, 1
1000, 0
```

Is there anyway I can do this as the case statement I got does not work?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Which database platform are you using? Sql Server, MySql, Postgres, Oracle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your case as

```
CASE WHEN count(MainAsset) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

but you'll have to add all the other columns in your select to a group by clause.

Comment: Hi, based on my understanding, if you do that, doesnt it just base the count on only on the results in the view? As I have got about 5 where clauses which I haven't posted to here but the exact where clauses shouldnt matter. I need the count to be based off the full table, not the aliased table in the view. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly, but if you want the count to not be affected by where conditions, you may need to use left joins instead of inner joins; that will preserve all the rows in your first table (RENT_ACCOUNTS) even if they don't join with the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your `case` expression using an `exists()` like so:

```
, case when exists (
      select 1 
      from RENT_ACCOUNTS as i 
      where i.MainAsset = RENTACC.MainAsset
      group by i.MainAsset
      having count(*) > 1
    ) 
      then 1 
    else 0 
    end as Multi_MainAsset
```

Depending on your platform, it might be better to use subquery to derive `RENTACC` with a `count(*) over()` instead

```
select ...
  , case when MainAssetCount > 1 then 1 else 0 end as Multi_MainAsset
from (
  select *
    , count(*) over (partition by MainAsset) as MainAssetCount
  from RENT_ACCOUNTS 
  ) AS RENTACC
...
```